# R range referencing with different dimensions not causing an error

Tags: r, dataframe

In using range referencing I normally expect to see an error or at least a warning message when the operations in '[' ']' do not match the dimensions of the parent object, however I have just discovered that I am not seeing said warnings and errors. Is there a setting for this or a way to force an error? Example:

```
x = 1:5
y = 10:12
x[y>10]
y[x>2]
```

likewise this applies to data frames and other R objects:

```
dat = data.frame(x=runif(100),y=1:100)
dat[sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),23),c(TRUE,FALSE)]
```

The silent repetition and truncation of the references to match the dimensions of the parent object is unexpected, having used R for years, I've somehow never noticed this before.

I'm using R Console (64-bit) 3.0.1 for Windows (could be updated yes, but I hope this isn't the cause).

Edit: Fixed data.frame example as data.frame's don't allow more column references than columns. Thanks zero323.

Comment: With a piece of code you've provided I get simple  `Error ... undefined columns selected`.

Comment: Nope, subsetting doesn't check if the lengths match. If it did, it would be annoying for many cases where recycling is intended like `x[c(TRUE,FALSE)]` to take every other value. Or for that matter `x[TRUE]` to take every value - which may be useful programmatically.

Comment: @thelatemail In regards to the intention of recycling, I definitely do agree on the case of `x[TRUE]`  and I see the case for recycling for divisors of length(x). The truncation case and recycling for non-multiples, I would expect to be normally an unintended behaviour for most users and should at least throw the warning. @josilber covers these cases with his solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the `` `[.data.frame` `` function to throw a warning when indexing with a logical vector that doesn't evenly divide the number of rows:

```
`[.data.frame` <- function(x, i, j, drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 1) {
  if (!missing(i) && is.logical(i) && nrow(x) %% length(i) != 0) {
    warning("Indexing data frame with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide row count")
  }
  base::`[.data.frame`(x, i, j, drop)
}
```

Here's a demonstration with the 150-row iris dataset, passing logical indexing vectors of length 11 (should cause warning) and 15 (should not cause warning):

```
iris[c(rep(FALSE, 10), TRUE),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 22           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa
# 33           5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
# 44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
# 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
# 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
# 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
# 88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
# 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
# 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica
# 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica
# 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
# 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.frame`(iris, c(rep(FALSE, 10), TRUE), ) :
#   Indexing data frame with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide number of rows

iris[c(rep(FALSE, 14), TRUE),]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
# 30           4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
# 45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa
# 60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
# 75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
# 90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor
# 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
# 120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica
# 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica
# 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I'm guessing that it is meant to be length(j) not length(cols). Otherwise it seems to work as expected, I was thinking of something like this but I've never been game to overwrite anything built-in in case I hadn't allowed for certain cases, your answer seems to.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @josilber I've written the following for atomic vector and matrix subsetting in case anyone else wants it:

```
`[` <- function(x, i) {
if(!missin

g(i) && is.logical(i) && (length(x) %% length(i) != 0 || length(i) > length(x))) {
        warning("Indexing atomic vector with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide row count")
    }
    base::`[`(x,i)
}

`[` <- function(x,i,j,...,drop=TRUE) {
    if (!missing(i) && is.logical(i) && nrow(x) %% length(i) != 0) {
        warning("Indexing matrix with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide row count")
    }
    if (!missing(j) && is.logical(j) && nrow(x) %% length(j) != 0) {
        warning("Indexing matrix with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide column count")
    }
    base::`[`(x,i,j,...,drop)
}
```

Testing my original example afterwards with this modification now produces the warning and other operations behave as per normal:

```
> x = 
1:5
> y = 10:12
> x[y>10]
[1] 2 3 5
Warning message:
In x[y > 10] :
  Indexing atomic vector with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide row count
> y[x>2]
[1] 12 NA NA
Warning message:
In y[x > 2] :
  Indexing atomic vector with logical vector that doesn't evenly divide row count
> x[x>2]
[1] 3 4 5
> x[1:2]
[1] 1 2
```